# VBA Excel: Can't find member objects on enable macros

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a ComboBox in an Excel sheet, let's call it Sheet2. I have a Sub in Sheet2 for `ComboBox1_Change()` that, among other things, modifies the ListFillRange for another ComboBox. Whenever I open the sheet in a new location, I have to enable macros, but this automatically triggers `ComboBox1_Change()` for some reason (if it could not, this would fix my issue), then I get the error "Compile error: Method or data member not found" on the line

```
Sheet2.ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "'Lists'!C2:C5"
```

If I break the macro, then any time I change ComboBox1, it runs fine. It's only on this initial run that any error is thrown.

Is there a way to make this macro NOT run when macros are enabled? Or is there a reason it can't find an object at the beginning that any other time it can find?

Comment: Do you have any code in auto_open for the workbook?

Comment: Compile time error does not mean your code is being run...

Comment: You're right, my bad. The question still stands, why can't it find the object in the sheet at compile time, but it appears that the code is functional afterwards?

Comment: And no, I don't have any code in auto-open